# Converting 8bit unsigned PCM into 8bit signed PCM

Tags: c, audio, pcm

How can I convert an unsigned 8bit PCM stream (0-255) into a signed 8bit PCM stream (-128-127). Is it as simple as subtracting 128 from every unsigned byte so that 0 becomes -128 and 255 becomes 127? Or is it more complicated?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should add the tag of the programming language you want to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try it?
In my opinion it should suffice but I don't know what language you are using.

When working with signed and unsigned integer/char bear in mind that the internal representation for negative values is the two's complement.
Safest would be to calculate in `signed int` size to avoid overflows.

Comment: I'm looking at some code that I did not write and it does weird things just to convert unsigned to signed. In fact here's what it does: "signed char result = ((signed char) (x + 128)) * 257;" (C code). The variable "x" is of type "unsigned char" and contains the sample to convert. I don't get this code at all. Where does the * 257 come from? But it works!?

Comment: Well multiplying with 257 and then clamping to char size is like multiplying with 1 so it should work but you can leave 257 out. Maybe the original programmer wanted to scale a 0-1 range and had problems but who knows?

Comment: Yeah, seems like leaving out the * 257 doesn't change anything. So I hope it's ok to remove this and not break anything... maybe it was some workaround for some ancient compiler bugs!?

Comment: As I already stated maybe the programmer wanted to scale a [0.0, 1.0] interval at first with 256 which would result in the right result for this interval but in the code you gave it would return 0. Maybe then he fiddled with the value until 257 worked out but we can only guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So in any case, the answer is that it is as easy as subtracting 128 from the unsigned value!

Answer (score 0):

For the code you posted in your comment, subtracting 128 will reverse the previous operation and will give you the signed data.